# TextMate: gear menu won't open with Ctrl-Escape

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, textmate

I am trying to open the gear menu when the caret is inside e.g. an 'echo' inside a .php file. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Esc</kbd> does nothing.

Can someone think of a way to debug this?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any custom keyboard shortcut defined? Any application launcher like QuickSilver or similar?

Comment: Did you install some program with global keyboard shortcuts, such as Launchbar, Quicksilver, Alfred, Butler, KeyRemap4Macbook, FastScripts? Are you running the TextMate 2 preview (icon is a flower) instead of the stable release of TextMate? Are you running Remote Management or Screen Sharing on your Mac?

Comment: TextMate is the regular stable version. I am running some programs that have global shortcuts (ShiftIt e.g.), but haven't yet found one that uses that shortcut. How would I find the shortcut in ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist?

Comment: Run `plutil -convert json -o foo.plist ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist` and open `foo.plist` in TextMate. Reformat Document from the JavaScript bundle. Search for an occurrence of `53` in one of the entries, that's `Escape`'s key code.

Comment: Hmm... I checked the plist, there is only one occurence of 53, and that is not in conjunction with 262144, but with 1048576, which should be cmd...

Comment: Does it happen on other user accounts? If not, what applications are set to launch at login, both in *Accounts & Groups* preference pane and as `~/Library/Launch Agents`? If you remove all of them, log out and back in, does it work again? // Please respond to comments using @ notifications to ensure the users who posted the comments get notified about your responses. For me, use @DanielBeck, it even autocompletes.

Comment: @DanielBeck: I will need to try that. For now, I have tested with a fresh user account (which did not help). Thank you for the time being...

Comment: @JosephTura To clarify, a newly created, "empty" user account where no applications are started upon login has the same problem in TextMate?

Comment: @DanielBeck To be honest, I did not check whether anything was started, or rather "Little Snitch" was started, but I uninstalled that and tried afterwards, and that did not work either. I am beginning to think that I am misinterpreting the TextMate manual... Can keyboard shortcuts in TextMate be changed? I would probably do that then...

Comment: If they can be changed, switching to a newly created user account should reset all customization, unless you modified TextMate itself. If you think this is possible (or even otherwise and you have the two minutes to do it) I suggest you just download a pristine copy and test it again. Also, what happens when you run [Key Codes](http://manytricks.com/keycodes/), does it detect the `Ctrl-Esc` key combination as key down/key up pair?

Comment: @DanielBeck Good point. It does not. It recognizes Esc as key-down-up, it recognizes ctrl as a modifier, but it does not detect the combination.

Comment: Does Key Codes also fail for your second account you just created today? Do you have a second keyboard you can try to make sure it's not a hardware issue? Do you have a secondary system you can boot to see whether the issue occurs there, too? What happens when you run `cat -v` in Terminal and press `Ctrl-Esc`, does it print something? If so does it print something when you boot from Mac OS X installation DVD, and, without starting the installation, open Terminal and run `cat -v` there?

Comment: @DanielBeck I have not yet rebooted, played around with Key Codes. It detects shift-esc, shift-ctrl-esc but not ctrl-esc. Can that be globally disabled? Using cat, the combination does nothing. I have tried two keyboards. And apparently the key itself is just fine. The combo must be disabled somewhere...

Comment: @JosephTura Have you checked the *Keyboard Preference Pane*, whether the shortcut is assigned to some special function, especially the *Keyboard & Text* section in *Keyboard Shortcuts*? I know, you checked the `plist`, but let's make sure. And I'm still not sure you checked everything on the other account, your replies leave room for interpretation. It just takes a minute to verify. Also, I suggest you do reboot, just to be sure it's not some weird glitch.

Comment: @DanielBeck I have checked the Keyboard Preference Pane multiple times. I also tried in the other account, no luck. Rebooting didn't help. I feel incredibly stupid, because I am sure I am doing something wrong. Just don't know what. I am officially giving up. Maybe I'll take the thing to an Apple Store and see what they can do...

Comment: Thank you so much for your patience and your many suggestions!!!

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry we couldn't determine the cause. But when you need to restart the next time, pop in the DVD and check the installer's Terminal to see whether `Ctrl-Esc` produces a `^[` escape sequence. This will tell you whether it's hardware related.